# How to get current time hour in system time format

Tags: ios, swift

I need to get the current hour and minute as per the system time format, e.g for system time 7:05 PM, sysHour should be 7. For 19:05, sysHour should be 19

Currently, I am using the code below but it gives sysHour = 19 instead of 7.

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let sysHour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
let sysMinutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
```

Please help

Thanks

Comment: just get the hour using `truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 12)` for double and for integer `sysHour % 12`

Answer (score 3):

Use a `DateFormatter` using `.short` or maybe `.medium` for the `timeStyle`.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.timeStyle = .short
formatter.dateStyle = .none
let time = formatter.string(from: Date())
```

The result will depend on the user's locale and their time settings.

Comment: Glad to help. Please don't forget to indicate that your question has been answered by accepting the best answer to your questions.